# Sample from distribution important sampling

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo

I am currently studying Monte Carlo methods and have some trouble understanding how to use importance sampling to perform Monte Carlo integration. What I don't understand will probably be best shown with an example.

Say I have some function $f(x)=x(1-x)$ and I want to estimate the integral of it between $0$ and $1$. To do it I use importance sampling. I choose $p(x)=\sin(x)$, then the integral is equal to $\frac1N \sum\frac{f(x)}{p(x)}$, but I need to sample my points accordingly to the distribution $\sin(x)$ and I am a bit unsure on how to do it in practice.
If I generate random numbers uniform on $(0,1)$ and the evaluate that for pdf $\sin(x)$ so that I get my points from $points=\sin(x)$, and then to obtain the integral I just evaluate my sum with the points I just sampled. When I try to do so I get a value very far from true value of $1/6$.

The result is way better when I just sample $X$ as normal distribution and do ordinary Monte Carlo integration. What do I do wrong and how should I think about it?

Comment: 1. $p$ should be a density on $[0,1]$; yours is not. 2. Your procedure generates samples from the distribution of $p(U)$ where $U \sim \text{Uniform}[0,1]$, which is different from sampling from the distribution with density $p$.

Comment: I suggest you use $p(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}sin(\pi x)$.  This seems to be your intent.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I want p(x) = pi/2sin(pix) but how do I get the samples? Are they just generated as random numbers evaluated at p(x)?

Comment: No, plugging in samples from $\text{Uniform}[0,1]$ into a density $p$ will not give you samples from that density. Instead, if you [plug in those $\text{Uniform}[0,1]$ samples into the inverse CDF $F^{-1}$ of your desired distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling), then you will obtain samples from that distribution.